# Scriptural basis for Sadhguru's claim that Yaśodā also became one of the gopīs?

Tags: puranas, krishna, reference-request, yashoda, sadhguru-jaggi-vasudev

https://isha.sadhguru.org/us/en/wisdom/article/krishna-women-in-his-life

> Yashodha’s relationship with Krishna grew in such a way that **she also became one of the Gopis. She was also part of the Raas.** She did not like Radhe because she thought this girl was too forward, whatever that meant. Radhe did not have the normal demeanor that was expected of a village girl. She was a little too outgoing. Yashodha felt this girl was hijacking her wonderful son, but she could not help joining the Raas conducted by Radhe after Krishna left.

Does Bhāgavata or any other Purāṇa support this claim?

Comment: He talks on Hinduism and popularity. No scriptural basis. But considering many celebrity gurus, he sometimes speaks sensible things! So, you can take what is good and ignore what is not.

Comment: @sv. Please approve the edit. So that we may get an answer if we frame the question differently. Also I will try to offer bounty to this question.

Comment: Sorry, can't accept your edit. If I remove details about the person who made the claim users will ask for the source of the claim & may vote to close. Both our questions are asking for the same source. No edit required. @MrGreen

Comment: @sv. But here's the advantage in the edit. You need not give them a source of a question. Its just a question. Like did Rama got to Lanka? There's no claim being done here, its just asking a question. Insted if you do put as quoted by some person, they will say go ask that person and shifts the burden of proof and simply will start commenting about the person instead of doing a genuine search. Just look at the answer here, it doesn't even address the question instead it goes onto say about the person. This can be avoided in the edit

Comment: @sv. If  you disagree, then can you please mark this question as not a duplicate?

Comment: Sadhguru's clarification - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0a4cqiQZ1U

Comment: @MrGreenGold You must be new here. People here downvote and vote to close if you can't back up your claim. E.g., see [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1583/what-citation-standards-are-expected-of-questions) meta post. So the only way to avoid closure is to cite a popular personality making the claim. You can ignore/downvote the currently posted answer if you don't like it. You can't really stop users from posting such answers.

Comment: @sv. If you mention popular person's name then inevitably the burden of proof falls on him. But a question needs no backing. Because a question is not claiming anything, for backup. A question is not a claim. It doesn't need a backup. So for my question answer's like this won't even crop up

Comment: @sv. If you disagree with me please help me in marking my question as not a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @MrGreenGold 'A question is not a claim. It doesn't need a backup.' - You are talking about the ideal scenario but I'm just explaining how things work here. Whether you mention the source of the claim or not, the burden of proof does not fall on the source or OP. Read the last line of my question: "Does Bhāgavata or any other Purāṇa support this claim?" It's not asking if Sadhguru is right, wrong or if he has really studied any scriptures, yet someone posted an answer challenging the source. I repeat, both our Q's are looking for the scriptural source. You can flag the mods to reopen your Q.

Comment: @sv. I totally agree with you. But people here simply don't get the point. Look at the answer your question has. It is completely irrelevant and it has four upvotes as of now. The answerer just took the advantage of you naming the person who claimed it instead of answering it. This exactly what my phrasing of the question avoids

Comment: @sv. Again I'm requesting you, try accepting my edit and flagging the existing answer as not an answer.

Comment: @sv This is about Rasa Vichar and Rasa lila and other pastimes are called Nitya Lila happening in the spiritual world.In the spiritual world all jivas are in either one of the 5 rasas.Shanta,Dasya, Sakhya, Vatsalya,and Madhurya.Any one particular exchange is nitya siddha in every Jiva.Yashodha Maiya is situated in Vatsalya rasa and the Gopis are in Madhurya rasa.There since rasa is nitya siddha there is no change in it. Its all by mistake baddha jivas attribute one rasa to another and it is called Rasabhasa dosha.This dosha does not happen in the Nitya lila of the Lord.

Comment: Srila Rupa Gosvami, the chief disciple of Lord Sri Caitanya Mahaprabhu,has syatematically described the transcendental symptoms displayed by pure devotees of Radha Krishna. This is the link for the english translation of the book, this contains all the Rasa Vichara according to Sastra and the Nitya Lila of the Lord prabhupadabooks.com/nod

Comment: @MrGreenGold lol, why did you waste the bounty space addressing me? you could've simply stated "I don't like the answer currently posted. Looking for a thorough answer that doesn't attack the claim or source of the claim"

Comment: @sv. Oh ok. That is more reasonable. But I did it in matter of hurry, sorry for that

Comment: @sv.  no answer, bounty wasted

Answer (score 5):

Sadhguru Jaggi Vasudev has not read scriptures. In one of [his discourse](https://youtu.be/bvGVwdpc_II), he makes it abundantly clear; I have transcribed the part where he says that:

> **me as a person, I always avoided learning Sanskrit language, though I have immense liking towards the language I avoided learning it when I had the opportunities to learn because the moment you learn Sanskrit you will end up reading the scriptures. My own vision has never failed me even for a moment in my life. I didn't want to clutter myself with traditions and scriptures and other things, right now  everything I do is purely simply from the source not cluttered with any traditions, any scriptures, any teachings, simply looking at life. So I didn't want to read scriptures;** I consciously avoided Sanskrit language. And that day I was sitting alone and it's in terms of visual beauty, it's the most incredible place that you can think of.....

Based on above comment made by himself, It is highly unlikely that his point of view on Yashodha becoming one of gopis, not like Radha etc will have any scriptural support.

Comment: 'It is highly unlikely that his point of view ... will have any scriptural support' - that's not enough according to the meta discussion [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/612/what-to-do-with-those-type-of-questions-whose-answers-are-simple-yes-or-no#comment2040_613). You also need to produce some counterevidence from scripture showing how Sadhguru is wrong.

Comment: @sv - Not interested in repeating this discussion with you. If someone has made a statement then he or his followers need to support it. Your question is limited to whether it has scriptural support. That is clearly not the case as he has not read the scriptures. If your argument is that it can be by coincidence then please wait for one of his apologists to provide proof.

Comment: @Carmensandiego this sinply does not answer the question